# Cannot install slurm seff in debian 9 (stretch)

Tags: slurm

In a cluster of debian 9 machines, I have installed slurm via apt-get , but i see that seff command is not available.How could i install it?

I see that there is a folder contribs in the tar.gz file but no instructions are given on how seff (and other plugins) could be built.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `seff` command is a Perl script. There is no need to compile/build it. Just copy it to a location present in your PATH env variable and you should be able to use it. The same holds for the `smail` command, it is a Bash script, no need to build it.

Comment: When I try to run the perl script it gives following error: Can't locate Slurmdb.pm in @INC. How can I download it?  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508367/how-to-install-slurm-seff-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution, but I was having the same problem, and the solution for an ubuntu 20.04 was to install libslurmdb-perl. I already had installed libslurm-perl.

In debian maybe the name of the package is different.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Yes,it is of indeed a perl script but when i try to run it
i receive:

"Can't locate Slurmdb.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Slurmdb module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at ./seff line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./seff line 11."

So it seems it cannot see the module Slurmdb.pm
Where this module should be and why really it is not included in INC?
Thanks